# Search a contact using phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts

I would like to retrieve the name of the contact associated with an incoming message number.
I came up with the following code.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(msgSender));
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);

        try {
            c.moveToFirst();
            displayName = c.getString(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally{
            c.close();
        }
```

The problem is, its working on emulator but not working on my mobile device. I tried restarting my phone. But still not working. I searched found codes similar to this one but is not working on actual phone.

Comment: what version does your read phone is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply below code to work in Real Mobile with android version 2.1

```
    //String msgSender="Mobile No";
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(msgSender));
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
    try {
        c.moveToFirst();
     String  displayName = c.getString(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }finally{
        c.close();
    }
```

in Android 2.1 we have to use `ContactsContract` and also `PhoneLookup` should be of `ContactsContract`.

Make sure you have given below permission.

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: in My Mobile it's Working on HTC Incredible S.